# As thanks, I can help with looking anything up on paywalled resources

Tags: discussion

I know that I've asked many questions (apologies!), but can't answer them as I'm benighted in law.

Thus to convey my many grateful thanks, I can proffer to help anyone who needs content from subscription and paywalled content that I can access. Hope this is allowed?

Comment: Sadly everything I'd want is unrelated to law. If you happened to have ISO/IEC 10118-3:2018 though... You could make a change by contributing to the research community via Sci-Hub.

Answer (score 6):

The sentiment is appreciated, but I should point out that paywalls relate to contractual agreements and copyright law. There are many resources behind the Lexis Nexus paywall, which I cannot directly link (password protected), and where the terms of use prohibit making a copy and posting it out there in the wild. It is fairly likely that any paywall system has such a restriction. That would include substantial cut and paste or pdf-and-post – but limited quoting in the context of a question or answer is fair use.

Comment: But I can copy and paste cases? Or download documents as PDF and send them?

Comment: And do you have anything you'd like me to look up for you?

Comment: Many paywalled papers can be found legally elsewhere. You'll find that papers from decades ago that are _all over_ and even published on the website of the university where it came from may also be behind paywalls from another site.

Comment: You pay the company for *collecting and making it easily accessible* - sure you can get them for free... but you don't have the luxury of getting everything at one spot on a silver platter.