# Why aren't my Contract Law questions and answers being upvoted more?

Tags: discussion

I'm forlorn and heavyhearted. I spent quite much time and effort to post referenced answers and deep questions on contract law to learn more, but too many of them are downvoted or get zero votes. Why?

I don't know what more to do. [I've proffered to assist with providing pay-wall material.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/827/25327)

I'm not a technie and don't know how to verify, but are we upvoting less on Law SE than average?

Answer (score 4):

### Because there aren't that many of us

Feel free to play with this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/law/query/1194682/monthly-active-users-on-law) of 'active' users.

Running it today (18 Feb 2020) gives the following results:

- Law: 18
- Academia: 28
- English: 51
- Stack Overflow: 11,373

Even if you post the greatest question ever written, eminently upvotable, only a small number of people will see it.

**Unless**, that question is lucky enough to become a featured question. When that happens, every user on every stack sees it - including those 11,000+ on Stack Overflow - and the question gets a disproportionate amount of votes.

Comment: And don't be confused by some posts here with scores of votes.  Those are virtually always because the question spent time on the Hot Network Questions list.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Dale M's answer when it comes to probable reasons. Still, I imagine you are looking for something that you can do, other than accept your fate.
In the realm of questions, I note that you often post answers with a snapshot of a textbook page, some underlining, and then ask a question about the meaning of that part of the text. This is not a well-received genre of questioning on LSE, and I think a substantial part of the reason is that they primarily ask for a psychological analysis of an author, rather than a statement of what the law is. This is especially problematic when you put forth a series of questions about the same textbook. I personally skip textbook questions, though I might take notice of such a question that compared and contrasted a half-dozen textbook sources in their treatment of a concept, provided that it was the essential text (providing that you have *some* comprehension of the topic and can summarize that part), and is not a page screen-shot.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to reasons provided previously, **offering to *break the law* trying to help a *law Q&A website*** suggests not understanding sufficiently the purpose of Stack Exchange generally, or this community in particular, or a mismatch between your expectations and what the community actually does.

Have you read through much of Law Meta? Reviewed questions and answers that have significant amounts of upvoting and/or were written by high-rep users, to gain greater insight into what leads them to be voted so? Paid attention to the comments left on your posts, and those left on similar posts that were written by others?

Comment: "offering to break the law" : I don't understand?

Comment: Given how many questions about it we get, into surprised you haven't seen [tag:copyright] before. Copyright law is kind of a big thing, and breaking it is kind of a big thing too.