# How can we advertise Law SE on legal Reddits?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone here subscribe to, and is well known at, r/ask_lawyers, r/auslaw, r/law, r/lawyers (application and lawyer ID required), r/lawcanada, r/lawschool, [r/lawschooladmissions](https://old.reddit.com/r/lawschooladmissions), [r/legaled](https://old.reddit.com/r/legaled), r/uklaw?

I was flabberghasted that [we have just 18 active users](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/974/25327). Peradventure someone can advertise on these subreddits to try to convince users there to participate here?

Comment: For context, the query returning 18 active users seems to define 'active' as at least 5 non-negative Qs or As in the last 30 days.

Comment: Always worth trying to expand the community and its activity!  [Related from 4 years ago](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/10).

Comment: @feetwet Thanks. I forgot I posted there. I thought to narrow the target to Reddit.

Comment: Could someone explain why Community deleted [my answer](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/978/2)? It is unclear why it was "*flagged as spam or offensive*". The answer certainly addresses the core of OP's question (that is, the low number of active users on Law SE) and gives several verifiable examples of the point made in the answer.

Comment: @NNOXApps Apps wish I would have been advertised this site to much earlier! :( I really am bummed about even thinking about it.