# Does (Law) StackExchange reach out to law schools and professors?

Tags: discussion

To my pleasant surprise, I just spotted that [George Mason University's Antonia Scalia Law School](https://www.law.gmu.edu/library/freelegalresearch) touts us!

> [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com)
> Question-and-answer forum for legal professionals, students, and others with an interest in law

Does (Law) Stack Exchange advertise to law professors, and schools? If not, ought we? I am rooting for self-promotion!

At minimum, how can we convince law faculties to link to us as a legal resource?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/975/18505). It merely suggests another target.

Comment: Cool to see that!  But this Q might also might be a duplicate of https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79/how-do-we-attract-and-retain-legal-experts